# What does it mean by saying "Comparable affects the original class but Comparator doesnt"

Tags: java, collections, comparator, comparable

```
// Original class Dog
  class Dog{
   String name;
   int age;

}

//Case 1
    class Dog implements Comparable<Dog>{
             //compareTo() implementation
        }


//Case2
      class Dog implements Comparator<Dog>{
       // compare() implementation
    }

//Case 3

    class DogNameComparator implements Comparator<Dog>{
    // compare() implementation
}



 Collection.sort(dogList);
    Collectios.sort(dogList,new DogNameComparator());
    Collection.sort(dogList,new Dog());
```

Isnt it true that in case 2 the original class is actually modified even though they say Comparator doesnt modify the original class ?

 May be if i have not understood the concept correctly, do enlighten me on it.

Comment: Your example is flawed (or incomplete), there is no requirement that the second example provide `Comparator` itself (in fact that does make the difference difficult to see). But notice the third example is independent of `Dog`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Comparable` can only ever be implemented on the original class, and so there can only ever be one implementation for it (unless you override `compareTo` using a subclass). Meanwhile, `Comparator` is not required to be implemented on the original class, so there can be many implementations.

Your second case is quite different from the first case, in that `compare` will have access to three `Dog` instances (`this`, parameter #1, and parameter #2), while `compareTo` would have access to only two `Dog` instances (`this` and parameter #1).

Comment: Thank you!!!..But still, that line "Comparator doesnt affect the original class" is bothering me because even though case 2 is not the way its done, its still an allowed implementation right and it forces the Dog class to implement compare(), so the Dog class is actually getting affected by Comparator right?

Comment: @ShyamSreenivasan Right, the way you have it implemented, case 2 shows `Dog` being affected by `Comparator`, but in practice a class is never used as its own `Comparator`, because it's easy to get the 3 instances that I mentioned confused, and one of the primary uses for `Comparator` is that you don't need an instance of the original class in order to have the ability to compare 2 instances.

Comment: Alight!That's cool.But just wondered why Java even allows us to do that in the first place.Thank you!